# Looking for PHP cURL proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I'm writing a crawler, but keep getting banned from the sites I'm crawling. I looked into some solutions and the best, I think, was using a proxy.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
```

Could someone tell me some proxy's I can use for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the list I was looking for: http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/